# Git Rebasing child of child branches

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

Currently, We follow this branching structure for our development.

We have the *develop* branch, then an *epic* branch for the epic and *feature* branches for stories in the epic.

The feature branches are merged into the epic and the epic into the develop.

The scenario: We take feature-branch-1 from epic, then work on it. Once done, we raise the PR and immediately start with feature-branch-2 from feature-branch-1 and so on.

So it looks like this,

```
develop: A -> B

epic: A -> B

feature-branch-1: A -> B -> C -> D 

feature-branch-2: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

The typical scenario is we get review comments and would have to change the commit C either amend it or commit. Once the PR is approved we rebase with epic which in either case goes to a different hash.

```
feature-branch-1: A -> B -> C -> D -> J -> K

rebasing,

feature-branch-1: A -> B -> P

feature-branch-2: A -> B -> C -> D -> E -> F
```

What is the best strategy to rebase feature-branch-2 on feature-branch-1 so that the commit history looks like this?

```
feature-branch-1: A -> B -> P

feature-branch-2: A -> B -> P -> E -> F
```

Currently, I do something like this to solve this:
I create a new feature branch with a dummy name and delete feature-branch-2 using.
$ git branch -D
create a new branch off the feature-branch-1 and cherry-pick the commit from the dummy branch.

This works but I feel it's not the optimal way to do it.

Please suggest a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that rebase is, assuming that the *real* work related to `feature-branch-2` is 3 *straight* commits:

```
git rebase feature-branch-2~3 feature-branch-2 --onto feature-branch-1
```

The trick is to realize that the branches are *independent* even if they are one on top of the other.